# Cycles Render Is in Low Quality But The Viewport Looks Great

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have a Blender file which consists of an ocean plane and a sky node. The render view looks great through the viewport and it even looks great through the camera view when I lock the view to the camera square. Why does it look extremely low res when I render an image? Btw I'm using Blender 2.92 on Windows 10 and I'm trying to render with Cycles Supported on my GPU which is a 3070.

This is a screenshot of the viewport. Notice how good it looks.
[image]

This is a rendered image. Notice that it looks really bad and low res.
[image]

Also here is the actual file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vln8otPH7Yl5ANLYmMzED9RlNtTMg9s9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yup thanks! Sorry I missed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it is because your resolution viewport is 30, but your render resolution just 7. If you want the same quality, raise it from 7 to 30 or - if you wanna have even better - raise to more.

[image]

result: (resolution 30)

[image]

result: (resolution 60)

[image]